# UIButton changing in custom cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I am using this code to change `UIButton` in my `UITableView`.
The problem is when I scroll the buttons of the table are changing without any reason.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(232, 88, 78, 24)];

if([[array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[Cell.contentView addSubview:button];
```

This is the `buttonClicked:` method:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.myTableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    if([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"1"];
    }
    else
    {
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"0"];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is happened because table view reuses it cells, you should in delegate methods `tableview:cellforrowatindexpath:` update your button's state or any other button's property.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your cell is being reused. Try this instead:

```
    UIButton *button; = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:34]; 
if (!button) {
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(232, 88, 78, 24)];
button.tag = 34; 

if([[array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
else
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[Cell.contentView addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: still not working, i pressed on button1, scrolling down, button5 and button6 changed to pic2. scrolling up, button1 changed back to pic1.

Comment: sorry, still the same problem.